# what happen if i delete apache log file?

Tags: apache

I have 4 files in /var/log/apache2 and I just deleted 2 of them (I do have backups). would it affect apache's logging capabilities? does apache automatically create files and write to them if they don't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will create new file automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The file is deleted but the file handle remains until you reload/restart apache, at least on Rhel 7.
You can verify this by running `sudo lsof | grep access_log` after deleting /var/log/httpd/access_log.
You might see the file automatically getting recreated some time later when logrotate runs, as that issues a reload which would then trigger the file to be created again.